# click() with links

Tags: javascript, html, click, dom-events

I have a page with a few links that are all like this:

```
<a href="/" class="answer-item" rel="0">10</a>
```

I would like to use the `click()` function to simulate a user's click on one of them, but it doesn't seem to work in my tests.

```
//Evaluate a mathematical expression from another part of the page
var numberAnswer = eval(document.getElementById("question-title").getElementsByTagName("b")[0].innerHTML);

//Builds an array with the links that may match the expression
var choices = document.getElementsByClassName('answer-item');

//Iterates through array to find a match then clicks it
for(var i in choices){
    if(choices[i].innerHTML == numberAnswer){
        choices[i].click();
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that `choices[i]` is the correct element.

Firefox does nothing, Opera does nothing, and click() is not available in Chrome (I think).

Also, I have tried to use `dispatchEvent()` in this form:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
choices[i].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This apparently returned `true` in Firefox and Chrome but did not change anything.

The most bothersome part is that a link with only the `href` attribute works fine with `.click()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Per discussion in the comment area, it seems that the behavior used in this answer is non-standard, or at least not consistent across user-agents. I am researching this issue further; if you use the information in this answer, please carefully check your code in all browsers to ensure it works as expected.

---

**EDIT 2**

Per the comment from the OP, there is a "just make it happen" approach that would work here. It has some downsides, namely that your bound events cannot call `preventDefault` -- this method will not respect it. You could build some kind of event wrapper that might be able to deal with this... anyway, here's the code and fiddle:

HTML:

```
<br><br>
<!-- I am totally misusing this API! -->
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/echo/js/?delay=0&js=The link was followed;" id="progra_link">Some link with an event that uses preventDefault()</a>
<br><br>
<button id="doit_btn">Programmatically click the link</button>
```

Script:

```
function do_program_click () {
    var lnk = document.getElementById('progra_link');
    var loc = lnk.href;
    if (!loc)
        return false;            
    // call this to fire events
    lnk.click();

    // then follow the link
    document.location = loc;
    return;
};
function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
  if (element.attachEvent)
   return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
  else
   return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
}

// bind an event to the link to test force event trigger
addEvent(
    document.getElementById('progra_link'),
    'click',
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Testing element click event, default action should have been stopped');
        return false;
    }
);
// bind event to the leeroy button
addEvent(
    document.getElementById('doit_btn'),
    'click',
    do_program_click
);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CHMLh/

---

**Original answer**

Your sample code is incomplete. If I take just the basics, it works correctly:

```
<script>
   var lnk = document.getElementById('test');
   lnk.click();
</script>
<a id="test" href="/" class="answer-item" rel="0">test link</a>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgejS/

I would re-evaluate your assumptions that you're dealing with the correct dom element.

On an unrelated note, this:

```
var numberAnswer = eval(document.getElementById("question-title").getElementsByTagName("b")[0].innerHTML);
```

... what? `eval` is evil -- if you're ever using it for any reason, question whether you have the right approach. Are you trying to get an integer out of a string? See `parseInt` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)), the right tool for this job:

```
// this line is still failure-prone...
var ele = document.getElementById("question-title").getElementsByTagName("b")[0];
var numberAnswer = 0;
if (ele)
   numberAnswer = parseInt(ele.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Not sure what browser you are using, but under Chrome your code does nothing (even with something other than `/` as the URL)

Comment: The jsFiddle I posted, in Firefox, navigates the results pane to jsFiddle's home page -- it follows the `/` url as expected. Will test in Chrome and update here.

Comment: Confirm - this does not work in Chrome. Will edit, thanks for the info.

Comment: Not a problem. I've revoked my downvote in anticipation of your edit.

Comment: Ok, it seems that this works on every browser except Chrome. That's the fault of Chrome, not of your code. I found several articles that cited this fact. So, +1  :)

Comment: Heh, do you have some of those articles? Funny thing is... I am finding it hard to justify why it DOES work in Firefox, by all indications it should not. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361 tells me that only a form submit button should respond with the default browser action upon calling `click()`. I was starting to think this was non-conforming behavior or even a bug... but if you say everyone else is doing it EXCEPT Chrome, that raises a whole new question! Guess who is going to be posting on wc3\public-html about this tonight :)

Comment: While I agree that `eval` is evil, I think it works well in this context because it is evaluating a mathematical expression.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. If you're [eval]uating mathematical expressions, then that's one of the rare instances where `eval` is the tool for the job. I would still question whether it is faster and more secure to determine the answer on the server-side, but you know your use case better than I. :)  I am still researching the question of whether `click()` **should** work or not, I am not finding any conclusive evidence that it should. Thus, my answer here is not looking like the best approach.

Comment: I just Googled for it. Here's one "article": http://unitstep.net/blog/2010/04/12/triggering-links-from-javascript-using-jquery/ (according to it, no browsers support it but as you've discovered, some actually do)

Comment: From the discussion, it seems that the answer is "click() will not work for this". I'm sure there is a different way of doing this, even if will require more effort. In the meantime, this is the answer.

Comment: Check out the second edit, @MarkM - http://jsfiddle.net/CHMLh/ has a solution that does the job... dirty

Comment: @Chris Oh my, that is quite ugly (no offence to your excellent coding skills, of course). Fortunately, I have been able to solve my problem through a completely unrelated method that allowed me to avoid having to "simulate a click" at all. Even so, I thank you for the consistent help.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

The HTML (note that I added an 'id' tag):

`<a id="answer-item" href="/" class="answer-item" rel="0">10</a>`

The JS:

```
document.getElementById('answer-item').click();
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't work on Chrome, but that's a limitation of the browser itself

Comment: Adding an id and using `getElementById()` did not work, but can you explain why it would? My code already gets the proper element.

Comment: It isn't "easy" -- the issue is more complex. Please see the comment discussion on my answer for more info. Basically, it is my finding that `click()` should NOT work in this instance, the fact that it does is non-standard and/or a bug.

Comment: In addition, since the OP is calculating a value and then iterating links to find the matching value, using `getElementById` is a non-starter without going back to a server-side solution that could create unique matching `id` values that would be used like `document.getElementById('answernumber'+numberAnswer)`