# jQuery .one("click") on anchor wrapper leads to href not followed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

This is a deceptively tricky little bit of HTML/JS that has either me or jQuery thrown for a loop (my money's on me).

**It's demoed in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/yneNB/1/).**

---

...but here's the scenario.  An anchor is wrapped with a span:

```
<span> the span
    <a onclick="alert('onclick HTML attritbute fired!')" href="http://www.href-attribute-    fired.com">the link</a>
    wraps the link
</span>
```

The span has a click handler that clicks the anchor.  This needs to be `.one()` to avoid looping forever because of event bubbling (I also tried `.on()` and `.off()` to short circuit the loop with the same result - see fiddle).

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert("jQuery click fired!");
});

$('span').one("click", function() {
    alert('(span clicked, let us see what other events fire...)');
    $(this).find('a').click();
});
```

---

What you'll notice when you click on the link itself is that:

1. `onclick` HTML attribute fired!
2. jQuery click fired!
3. (span clicked, let us see what other events fire...)
4. `onclick` HTML attribute fired!
5. jQuery click fired!
6. **the href is followed**

It loops through the JS events an extra time because of the event bubbling up to the span, which is a little goofy and inelegant but totally expected and makes sense to me.  The key part here is that after all the JS events are through, *the href is followed*.

When you click on the outer span, this is the order of events:

1. (span clicked, let us see what other events fire...)
2. jQuery click fired!
3. `onclick` HTML attribute fired!
4. **... {crickets!?!} ....**

Even though the anchor's JS `click` events have fired, **the href is never followed**.

---

I'm guessing that `.one()` doesn't unbind the click event for the `span` *until the second time through, after bubbling up from the `anchor`*, and at at that point, the event propagation completely dies.  Since the href is not followed until all click events are finished, when the signal dies at the `span` the `anchor` doesn't know to fire the go-to-href event.

...but is that really what happens? What gives?

What is a better way to approach this problem (I'd like to avoid JS pulling off the href and setting `window.location` manually for a variety of reasons)?

Comment: Mixing jQuery-assigned event handlers with handlers defined in HTML attributes is generally a really bad idea.

Comment: This reminds me of a question that came up a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000852/click-does-not-work-with-links

Comment: Have you tried a much simpler example where a click event handler on one element calls `click()` on an anchor element? I have, and it doesn't follow the link.

Comment: @GrahamClark [Just did](http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/yneNB/5/) after seeing Pointy's answer.  Palm-smacking in progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link is followed in the first instance (when you click it directly) because that's the way `<a>` tags work, and none of your handlers asks that the default behavior be cancelled.

Triggering a "click" via jQuery on an `<a>` tag explicitly does not follow the link; that's just how jQuery works.

Comment: +1 Wow, I can't believe I didn't know that!  All the other stuff was a total red herring.  FWIW I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteorpeter/yneNB/5/) with a button showing your point.

Comment: So, is there a way to explicitly trigger link hrefs (that's prettier than setting `window.location`)?

Comment: The jQuery documentation for `.trigger()` is really lousy.  If you want to duplicate what happens when a real "click" happens on an `<a>`, you have to grab the "href" property and assign it to `window.location.href`.

Comment: +1: This perfectly coincides with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000852/click-does-not-work-with-links) from a few days ago.

Comment: Many thanks!  (In my exact use case, this is bad news.  I have a variety of anchor actions I'll need to account for - a simple href, an onlick attribute to run, sometimes there is a jQuery click handler and the href is "javascript:void".  Just about every link action our app uses shows up in this list.  It won't be pretty!)